# How to convert this regular expression into Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to use this regular expression in Python:

```
 <(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>
```

(from [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/))

```
def removeHtmlTags(page):
    p = re.compile(r'XXXX')
    return p.sub('', page)
```

It seems that I cannot directly substitute the complex regular expression into the above function.

Comment: What's the error or problem you got?

Comment: Are you escaping the apostrophes in the regex with a backslash? Can we see the real code you have that isn't working?

Comment: that helps me: https://regex101.com/ (check the python flavor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine here. You're probably having trouble because of the quotes. Just triple-quote it:

```
def removeHtmlTags(page):
    p = re.compile(r'''<(?:"[^"]*"['"]*|'[^']*'['"]*|[^'">])+>''')
    return p.sub('', page)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove HTML tags, this should do it:

```
import re

def removeHtmlTags(page):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\<[^>]+\>', re.I)
    return pattern.sub('', page)
```

Comment: That wasn't the question, but the point of the original regex is to allow for angle brackets within attribute values.